# How to create and sign the amazon mws request string

Tags: objective-c

I have to create a amazon MWS integration with an iOS application the issue is that I am not able to create and sign the request please help me providing some code sample would be very good if you have any.

I have tried with going through documentation and creating the string but it says that the signature is invalid

Answer (score 1):

First of all You have to include the Crypto definitions to digest your Request

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonHMAC.h>
```

By using this function You can digest Your request. The key is the secret key provided by Amazon

```
NSString *calcSignature(NSString *aString, NSString *key)
{
    const char *cKey  = [key cStringUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    const char *cData = [aString cStringUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    // Calculate SHA256-signature
    unsigned char cHMAC[CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA256, cKey, strlen(cKey), cData, strlen(cData), cHMAC);
    NSData *HMAC = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:cHMAC
                                          length:sizeof(cHMAC)];

    // return Base64 encoded
    return [HMAC base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
}
```

Digest the following sample requestString

```
POST /Feeds/2009-01-01 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: mws.amazonservices.com
User-Agent: <Your User Agent Header>

AWSAccessKeyId=0PExampleR2
&Action=CancelFeedSubmissions
&FeedSubmissionIdList.Id.1=1058369303
&FeedTypeList.Type.1=_POST_PRODUCT_DATA_
&FeedTypeList.Type.2=_POST_PRODUCT_PRICING_DATA_
&MWSAuthToken=amzn.mws.4ea38b7b-f563-7709-4bae-87aeaEXAMPLE
&Marketplace=ATExampleER
&SellerId=A1ExampleE6
&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256
&SignatureVersion=2
&Timestamp=2009-02-04T17%3A34%3A14.203Z
&Version=2009-01-01
```

Now You can calc the signature

```
 NSString *signatureString = calcSignature(requestString, amazonSecretKey);
```

These signature is appended to the request and You should get the result. You can test a little and control if You sending the correct signature by using Amazon Scratchpad.

Comment: Can you please send me sample code For GetMatchingProductForId how will be the request and is there any body parameters with the request. Please help me in implementing with it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am working on iOS application for integrating amazon MWS with our application.I was able to create the signature but in response I am getting signature is invalid can you please provide me with sample code for requests.

Comment: But keep in mind Amazon is going to restrict the possibilities of using MWS. In future You have to be a accredited Developer.

Comment: Thank you so  much for your reply. I was in search of it. Onze again thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Please tell me what is KLAmazonPreferences file of?

Comment: It just keeping the Amazon Credentials. You should replace them by Your own in Code.

Comment: what is the KLAccountKey can you please tell what are the values for the variable.

Comment: NSISO8601DateFormatter * dateFormatter = [NSISO8601DateFormatter new];
    NSString * timeStampValue = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];is the format correct for timestamp value.

Comment: The accountKey is Your AccountId provided by Amazon the date formatter just returns the Time in the format: `2009-03-24T20:29:19:22Z`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195627/discussion-between-shaniraaj-and-ivion).